# Store user settings in WCF service hosted by a Windows service

Tags: wcf, windows-services, settings, persistent

I've created a WCF/REST service that is hosted by a Windows service.

The service has no database behind it, because there is no need for.

But I want to save some general settings (list of allowed users, output format settings, etc).
I've tried a `.settings` file and read / write with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"]`.

This works while service is running.

But if I stop and start service, the stored values are gone.

Is there any other mechanism to save settings persistent without any database behind?

Thank you for answering!

Comment: *Persistent store* = database. Get over it - you need one. Use it.

Comment: @marc_s This solution is a little bit too much for 4 or 5 strings. I thought about saving in App.config or a seperate XML-File but I don't know how to do that and where this file/config will stored.

Comment: Well, you can get very lightweight databases, too - doesn't have to be a huge item like an Oracle or SQL Server installation.... could be SQLite, or something "NoSQL" (like RavenDB or MongoDB) - easy to use, easy to set up

Comment: Does the service just need to read those settings?

Comment: @justMe To read and to store at stoping service yes. Alternative would be to Store in a client, start service, transfer settings,..., read settings and store in client, stop service from client

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the settings in the app.config file of your Windows Service (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Application Name" value="MyApplication" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>.
```

Then you can retrieve those settings as you mentioned by calling `string appName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Application Name"]`.
The AppSettings within your app.config are stored persistently and survive stopping an starting the service ;)